# Native-Base Installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, native-base

When I try to install `native-base` I get this error:

```
(node:6636) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: nayasetup@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from native-base@3.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"*" from native-base@3.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Hafiz Sikander.com\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hafiz Sikander.com\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-29T18_25_50_406Z-debug.log
```